# How to count data with a certain condition after group

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table.

```
dat <- read_csv(
    "name,cnt
     a,10
     a,22
     a,13
     b,4
     c,4
     c,5
     c,10"
  )

> dat
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  name    cnt
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a        10
2 a        22
3 a        13
4 b         4
5 c         4
6 c         5
7 c        10
```

I would like to calculate the # of rows that cnt is lower than the value of the current row after group by:

```
> dat
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  name    cnt  nrow
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        10     0
2 a        22     2
3 a        13     1
4 b         4     0
5 c         4     0
6 c         5     1
7 c        10     2
```

I tried to write a custom function to calculate the number of rows but I am stuck on the performance of a for loop. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `name` and count number of values greater than the current value.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(nrow = purrr::map_int(cnt, ~sum(. > cnt)))

#  name    cnt  nrow
#  <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1 a        10     0
#2 a        22     2
#3 a        13     1
#4 b         4     0
#5 c         4     0
#6 c         5     1
#7 c        10     2
```

---

In base R, we can create a custom function

```
get_count <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, function(i) sum(i > x))
}
```

and apply it using `ave` for each `name`

```
with(dat, ave(cnt, name, FUN = get_count))
#[1] 0 2 1 0 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a `rank`ing by group essentially:

```
ave(dat$cnt, dat$name, FUN=function(x) rank(x, ties.method="min")) - 1
#[1] 0 2 1 0 0 1 2
```

Comment: and using `data.table`: `dat[order(name, cnt), o := rowid(name) - 1L]`. should be quite fast. and if there are dupes `cnt` in a `name`, `dat[order(name, cnt), o := rleid(cnt) - 1L, name]`, which should be slower